# 'Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null' when using RenderScript on 2.3 emulator

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

RenderScript doesn't work on the Android 2.3 emulator.

```
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2; (316)
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2;' failed
04-04 15:37:39.146: E/dalvikvm(863): Could not find class 'android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$2', referenced from method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.setErrorHandler
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 890 (Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2;) in Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;
04-04 15:37:39.146: D/dalvikvm(863): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
04-04 15:37:39.146: D/dalvikvm(863): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0012 in Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.setErrorHandler (Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$RSErrorHandler;)V
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$1; (317)
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$1;' failed
04-04 15:37:39.146: E/dalvikvm(863): Could not find class 'android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$1', referenced from method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.setMessageHandler
04-04 15:37:39.146: W/dalvikvm(863): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 889 (Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$1;) in Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;
04-04 15:37:39.156: D/dalvikvm(863): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
04-04 15:37:39.156: D/dalvikvm(863): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0012 in Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.setMessageHandler (Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$RSMessageHandler;)V
04-04 15:37:39.156: E/RenderScript_jni(863): No GC methods
04-04 15:37:39.166: W/dalvikvm(863): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-04 15:37:39.166: W/System.err(863): android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null
04-04 15:37:39.176: W/System.err(863):  at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:945)
04-04 15:37:39.176: W/System.err(863):  at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:982)
04-04 15:37:39.176: W/System.err(863):  at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:968)
```

I'm using RenderScript support library with **SDK Tools 22.6.2, Build-tools 19.0.3**. It works well on the 4.1 device, and even on the 2.3 device.

project.properties

```
target=android-19
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=19.0.3
```

I tried to lower the Build-tools version, but the project won't build with `RenderScript support mode requires Build-Tools 19.0.3 or later.` error.

If I copy the `.so` files to the `libs` directory, it starts complaining about the duplicated file.

`Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/librsjni.so`

I'm new to using RenderScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is that RenderScript is not part of the 2.3 Emulator images.

Answer (score 0):

It means super class is not available for 2.3. Check if runs on android 2.2 and lower if not then it means its a sipport library issue. This would need to check with android support libraries available